# jquery Ui-dialog and ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

i'm using a jquery dialog to open a sign in form. it works fine on ff,chrome and even Ie6,7
but it's not working on ie8.

this is my function:

```
function showSignInDialog() {
   var email = GetEmailFromCookie();
   if (!IsNullOrUndefined(email)) {
   $("input[name$='LoginEmail']").val(email);
   $("#chkRememberMe").attr("checked", "checked");
   }
   if (!$('#signInForm').dialog('isOpen')) {
   $('#signInForm').dialog({ bgiframe: true,
                             modal: true,
                             resizable: false,
                             width: 330,
                             title: 'EZtrader Login',
                             buttons: { "Login": doLogin }
                           });
    $('#signInForm').dialog('open');
  }
}
```

on ie8 i get a unresponsive script which means there is an infinite loop of some sort.
i tried debugging it and the loop occurs in the jquery-ui js file when i try to open the dialog.
i thought maybe it had something to do with 
"HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)"
which i read about here: http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/04/23/what-happened-to-operation-aborted.aspx

and tried to move the script block and the dialog box around in the page but nothing seem to work.
please help...

Comment: (comment from @redsquare) : Can you paste all the code, especially the doLogin function specified in the buttons option. Also can you explain where the problem is. Is it after clicking the buttons inside the dialog or is it that the dialog does not even show?

Comment: Actually it is an Answer not a comment....!

Comment: dialog's open on creation unless specified otherwise with the autoOpen option.  I wonder if IE is puking because you're opening it twice, once by declaring it, and then with dialog('open');

Comment: nope it's not because of the extra dialog open although it is pretty useless. but when i change the modal to false it's seems to be working so i guess it has to do with the overlay...

Comment: have you included the bgIframe plugin also?

Comment: not sure about the plug-in, but if i don't have it shouldn't it fail on all browsers?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be it:
http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4758

IE8's not handling the window.resize function correctly.  You'll need to adjust your local version of jquery-ui from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Running into the exact same set of issues.  To get rid of the first issue,the "unable to modify..." error, set your script tag to be deferred=deferred.

The second issue has to do with ie8's JavaScript parser from what I can find out.  There appears to be no answer, although I hadn't thought about an iframe, which if that would solve the issue, bonus!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete must be used only on document.ready. 
Please move autocomplete init code into `$(document).ready(function(){ [place here] })` block and all will work fine.